# How to add multiple customers to one group on opencart at once?

Tags: opencart

Is there any way to add many customers to one group at once on opencart? Its too much of a work to add 7500 customers to different groups by one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add **all customers** to one group while you know the group ID, you can execute this SQL query in your preferred MySQL administration tool:

```sql
INSERT INTO <DB_PREFIX>customer_to_group (customer_id, group_id)
    SELECT customer_id, <GROUP_ID> 
    FROM <DB_PREFIX>customer
```

Replace `<DB_PREFIX>` with your DB table name prefix (or none if you are not using it).
Replace `<GROUP_ID>` by the numeric representation of the group you want the customers to be assigned to.

You can use a similar approach if you want to insert only few customers - but again you need to know their ID's or email addresses (i.e. some unique value that could identify each customer):

```sql
INSERT INTO <DB_PREFIX>customer_to_group (customer_id, group_id)
    SELECT customer_id, <GROUP_ID> 
    FROM <DB_PREFIX>customer
    WHERE customer_id IN (<ID1>, <ID2>, <ID3>, '<ID...>')
```

or

```sql
INSERT INTO <DB_PREFIX>customer_to_group (customer_id, group_id)
    SELECT customer_id, <GROUP_ID> 
    FROM <DB_PREFIX>customer
    WHERE email IN ('email@address.1', 'email@address.2', 'email@address.3', '...')
```

Let's say you want to assign only those customers living in USA (where the country ID is `<COUNTRY_ID>`):

```sql
INSERT INTO <DB_PREFIX>customer_to_group (customer_id, group_id)
    SELECT c.customer_id, <GROUP_ID> 
    FROM <DB_PREFIX>customer c
    LEFT JOIN <DB_PREFIX>customer_address ca ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id
    WHERE ca.country_id = <COUNTRY_ID>
    GROUP BY c.customer_id
```